# XCode warns "Instantiation of variable 'Singleton<Foo>::_instance' required here but no definition is available

Tags: c++, xcode, macos-sierra

A legacy code base has this construct:

```
template< typename T >
class Singleton {
private:
    static T* _instance;
public:
    inline static T& instance() {
        if (_instance == 0) { // warning here
            _instance = new T;
        }
        return *_instance;
    }
};
```

It is typically used like this:

```
class Foo : public Singleton<Foo>
{
};
```

The warning is generated from any file that includes `Foo.hh`.

Currently, `Foo.cpp` does include this line:

```
template<>
Foo* Singleton<Foo>::_instance = nullptr;
```

but it doesn't help the compilation. Is there a way to provide the definition of Singleton::_instance before Foo is defined?

XCode 9.2 Mac OS X 10.12.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your header file, add

```
template <typename T> T* Singleton<T>::_instance = nullptr;
```

This is still an out-of-line definition, but not tied to a particular specialization. You should then be able to delete the line

```
template<> Foo* Singleton<Foo>::_instance = nullptr;
```

as the non-specialized definition above already does the same for all instantiations.

Comment: you know, I could swear I had tried that (as well as moving the in-line method definitions out of line) and it didn't resolve the warnings. Yet, I re-implemented as you suggested and ... warnings gone. Sheesh.